# Create Database in SQLite with IONIC 3 + CORDOVA

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, android-sqlite

I am developing an app with SQLite that creates and lists users ...

[image: Screenshot]

For this I have created a service in which I create the database and two methods (create and list), it should be mentioned that there are no errors and I have imported everything correctly

database.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class DatabaseProvider {

  private db: SQLiteObject;
  private isOpen: boolean;

  constructor(
    public http: Http,
    public storage: SQLite) {

      if(!this.isOpen){
        this.storage = new SQLite();
        this.storage.create({ name: "data.db", location:"default" }).then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
          this.db = db;
          db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST usuarios (Codigo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Identificacion INTEGER, Nombre TEXT, Apellido TEXT)", []);
          this.isOpen = true;
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
      }
      }

crearUsuario(Identificacion:number, Nombre:string, Apellido:string){
  return new Promise ((resolve , reject) => {
    let sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (Identificacion, Nombre, Apellido) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    this.db.executeSql(sql, [Identificacion, Nombre, Apellido]).then((data) => {
      resolve(data);
    }, (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });  
  });
}

listarUsuario(){
  return new Promise ((resolve , reject) => {
    this.db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM usuarios", []).then((data) => {
      let arrayUsuarios = [];
      if(data.rows.length > 0){
        for (var i=0; i < data.rows.length; i++){
          arrayUsuarios.push({
            Codigo: data.rows.item(i).Codigo,
            Identificacion: data.rows.item(i).Identificacion,
            Nombre: data.rows.item(i).Nombre,
            Apellido: data.rows.item(i).Apellido,
          });
        }
      }
      resolve(arrayUsuarios);
    }, (error) => {
      reject(error);
    })
  });
}

}
```

in my view home.html I have a form and two buttons ... one lists the users and the other creates the users of the form

home.html:

```
<button ion-button block color="secondary" (click)="listarUsuario()">Listar Usuario</button>

<form [formGroup]="todo" (ngSubmit)="crearUsuario()" novalidate>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Nombre</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="Nombre"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item *ngIf="todo.get('Nombre').errors && todo.get('Nombre').dirty">     
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Apellido</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="Apellido"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item *ngIf="todo.get('Apellido').errors && todo.get('Apellido').dirty">      
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Indentificación</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="Identificacion"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!todo.valid">Crear Usuario</button>
</form>

<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of listaPersonas">
    <ion-item>      
      <h2>{{item.Nombre}} - {{item.Apellido}}</h2>     
    </ion-item>   
    <ion-item-options side="right">
      <button ion-button color="danger">
        <ion-icon name="delete"></ion-icon>
        Eliminar
      </button>
    </ion-item-options> 
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

my controller has the following code:

home.ts:

```
export class HomePage {

  private listaPersonas: any;
  private todo: FormGroup;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private database: DatabaseProvider, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.todo = this.formBuilder.group({
      Nombre: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(8)]],
      Apellido: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(8)]],
      Identificacion: ['', Validators.required],
    });

  } 

  crearUsuario(){
    console.log(this.todo);

      this.database.crearUsuario(this.todo.value.Identificacion, this.todo.value.Nombre, this.todo.value.Apellido).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.listarUsuario();
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }) 
    }

  listarUsuario(){
    this.database.listarUsuario().then((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.listaPersonas = data;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }    

}
```

I'm testing my application on a physical device, but it does not do anything ... do not create, do not list users, I guess I'm not creating the database, I'm new to IONIC 3 and to deploy my application on the physical device first I build with the command `ionic cordova build android` and then I deploy my app on the phone with the command `ionic cordova run android --device`

what am I doing wrong? How can I find the error by trying my app on a physical device? with my debugging console? where is the Ionic 3 database physically stored in my device (directory)? any help for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that the syntax for :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST usuarios (Codigo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Identificacion INTEGER, Nombre TEXT, Apellido TEXT)
```

is wrong.

That is the keyword is **`EXISTS`** and not **`EXIST`**. I'd suggest trying/using :-

```
db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios (Codigo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Identificacion INTEGER, Nombre TEXT, Apellido TEXT)", []);
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating table in sqlite you need to create storage first. You can do something like this:

```
 if (this.platform.is('cordova'))
          this.sqlite.create({
            name: 'fundamentos.offline',
            location: 'default'
          })
.then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql(CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST usuarios 
    (Codigo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Identificacion INTEGER, 
     Nombre TEXT, Apellido TEXT),[])
    .then(() => console.log('Table Created'))
    .catch(e => {
                console.error(JSON.stringify(e));
              });`
```

For reference:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/
https://www.djamware.com/post/59c53a1280aca768e4d2b143/ionic-3-angular-4-and-sqlite-crud-offline-mobile-app